# find list view choice mode multiple events

Tags: android

how to find checked events in choice mode multiple.

I am using ontemselected method it is not working for me

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("agents"));
            ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            list.setSelected(true);
            list.setClickable(true);
            list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                   Log.d("checked",""+arg2);        


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

            });

            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: You should edit your question with the code relating to this matter.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getcheckItemIds()` gives u the array of selected ids

> long[] checkedIDs = listviewName.getCheckItemIds();

hope this helps